# How to solve error while running a test suite: "TestHTMLReporter The filename, directory name, or volume label syntax is incorrect"

Tags: java, selenium, selenium-webdriver, testng

I'm trying to run a Testng.xml file in Eclipse and it is successfully opening the browser and executing the test but at the end, it is throwing the above error because of which the test case is marked as failed by TestNG.

Following  is the console output:

```
[RemoteTestNG] detected TestNG version 7.4.0
Starting ChromeDriver 105.0.5195.52 

    (412c95e518836d8a7d97250d62b29c2ae6a26a85-refs/branch-heads/5195@{#853}) on port 37386
    Only local connections are allowed.
    Please see https://chromedriver.chromium.org/security-considerations for suggestions on keeping ChromeDriver safe.
    ChromeDriver was started successfully.
    Sep 28, 2022 11:52:20 AM org.openqa.selenium.remote.ProtocolHandshake createSession
    INFO: Detected dialect: W3C
    [TestHTMLReporter] The filename, directory name, or volume label syntax is incorrect
    
    ===============================================
    Live Project Automation : Facebook
    Total tests run: 1, Passes: 0, Failures: 1, Skips: 0
    ===============================================
```

The code that I'm using in testng.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE suite SYSTEM "http://testng.org/testng-1.0.dtd">
    
<suite name="Live Project Automation : Facebook">
    <parameter name="browser" value="chrome"></parameter>
    <test name="Facebook launch test">
        <classes>
            <class name="com.testng.tests.SimpleTestng"></class>
        </classes>
    </test>
</suite> <!-- Suite -->
```

Java class file:

```
package com.testng.tests;
import org.openqa.selenium.WebDriver;
import org.openqa.selenium.chrome.ChromeDriver;
import org.openqa.selenium.edge.EdgeDriver;
import org.openqa.selenium.firefox.FirefoxDriver;
import org.testng.Assert;
import org.testng.annotations.AfterMethod;
import org.testng.annotations.BeforeMethod;
import org.testng.annotations.Optional;
import org.testng.annotations.Parameters;
import org.testng.annotations.Test;
import com.beust.jcommander.Parameter;

public class SimpleTestng {

    WebDriver driver=null;

    @BeforeMethod
    @Parameters("browser")
    public void launchBrowser(String browserName) {
        if (browserName.equalsIgnoreCase("chrome")) {
            System.setProperty("webdriver.chrome.driver", "Drivers\\chromedriver.exe");
            driver=new ChromeDriver();
        } else if(browserName.equalsIgnoreCase("firefox")) {
            System.setProperty("webdriver.gecko.driver", "Drivers\\geckodriver.exe");
            driver=new FirefoxDriver();
        } else {
            System.setProperty("webdriver.edge.driver", "Drivers\\msedgedriver.exe");
            driver=new EdgeDriver();
        }
        driver.manage().window().maximize();
    }
    
    @AfterMethod
    public void quitDriver() {
        driver.close();
    }
    
    @Test
    public void LaunchFB() throws InterruptedException {
        String url="https://www.facebook.com";
        String title="Facebook - login or sign up";
        driver.get(url);
        Assert.assertEquals(driver.getTitle(), title);
        Thread.sleep(4000);
    }
}
```

Comment: Check if there is a file [TestHTMLReporter] with some timestamp syntax like hh:mm:ss . If so, then remove the timestamp.